# How to view XML documentation when Visual Studio debug starts for an .NET Core MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

The documentation already auto-generates, however I would like an easy way to see it when the debugger launches and the browser window is opened.

What are my options? Are there easier ways to view the docs (as they would appear in the browser, not raw XML) while I am still in Visual Studio?

Thanks!

#### SOLUTION: The best solution I was able to find for this is a Visual Studio Plugin called GHOSTDOC, this can be found and installed with a quick google search and two clicks.

Comment: Hover on variable and you get three options : 1) String 2) Xml 3) Html.  Just select option 2.

Comment: @jdweng What do you mean "hover on variable"?

Comment: @jdweng I see, what I mean is I am fine with the XML I just want a way to see it when the debugger start launches the browser.